# search whole column with any word in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have one column where data is getting stored in DB.
Column name is testdata in db and the data are like this

```
1. Maruti Suzuki Alto vxi 2007
2. Hundyai i20 vxi 2011
3. Toyota fortuner vdi 2014
```

So I have to search these data by any name.
So if I search "Alto 2007" so 1 result will show which Maruti Suzuki Alto vxi 2007
and if I search Maruti 2007 than also it should display this result.

Kindly help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at MySqls [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: Can you change the way your data is being stored?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LIKE` operator.

Syntax:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

In your case, you can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE "%keyword%"
```

You can learn more **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)**

Comment: Like this, the statement will never match the example search, with additional words in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

If the table that you're using is of the type `InnoDB` or `MyISAM`, you can leverage [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) for this. To use, you need to create Full Text index on the column in question first, using ALTER TABLE or CREATE INDEX.

You can use it like below,

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
 WHERE MATCH (testdata) AGAINST ('Alto 2007');
```

This will return all the results that contain ANY of the words `Alto 2007` in column `testdata`.